Representations of unitary group on spaces of differential forms
This is a question on certain irreducible real representations of the unitary group. My main reference is Salamon's book "Riemannian geometry and holonomy groups".
The unitary group $\mathrm U(n)$ acts on $\mathbb C^n$ preserving the standard Hermitian form.
So $\mathrm{U}(n)$ acts on $V=\mathbb R^{2n}$ as a subgroup of $\mathrm{SO}(2n)$, thus preserving the corresponding Hermitian structure $(g,J)$. The two-form $\omega=g(J{}\cdot{},{}\cdot{})$ is non-degenerate.
Consider the spaces $\Lambda^{p,q}$ of complex forms of type $(p,q)$ over $V$.
We have identifications

$\Lambda^1V^* \otimes \mathbb C = \Lambda^{1,0} \oplus \Lambda^{0,1}$,
$\Lambda^2V^* \otimes \mathbb C = \Lambda^{2,0} \oplus \Lambda^{1,1} \oplus \Lambda^{0,2}$,
$\Lambda^3V^* \otimes \mathbb C = \Lambda^{3,0} \oplus \Lambda^{2,1} \oplus \Lambda^{1,2} \oplus \Lambda^{0,3},$

and so on. There are real $\mathrm{U}(n)$-representations (in Salamon's notation) $[\![\Lambda^{p,q}]\!]$, $p \neq q$, and $[\Lambda^{p,p}]$ such that
$$[\Lambda^{p,p}] \otimes \mathbb C = \Lambda^{p,p}, \qquad [\![\Lambda^{p,q}]\!] \otimes \mathbb C = \Lambda^{p,q} \oplus \Lambda^{q,p},$$
so we can write real $\mathrm{U}(n)$-decompositions

$\Lambda^1V^* = [\![\Lambda^{1,0}]\!]$,
$\Lambda^2V^* = [\![\Lambda^{2,0}]\!] \oplus [\Lambda^{1,1}]$,
$\Lambda^3V^* = [\![\Lambda^{3,0}]\!] \oplus [\![\Lambda^{2,1}]\!]$,

etc. Further, since $J\omega=\omega$ ($\omega$ is of type $(1,1)$) and wedging with $\omega$ gives injective equivariant maps $L\colon \Lambda^{p,q} \to \Lambda^{p+1,q+1}$ for $p \geq q$ and $p+q\leq n$, any $\Lambda^{p,q}$ splits as a direct sum $\Lambda_0^{p,q} \oplus L(\Lambda^{p-1,q-1})$. We can then refine the above decompositions as

$\Lambda^1V^* = [\![\Lambda^{1,0}]\!]$,
$\Lambda^2V^* = [\![\Lambda^{2,0}]\!] \oplus [\Lambda_0^{1,1}] \oplus \mathbb R$,
$\Lambda^3V^* = [\![\Lambda^{3,0}]\!] \oplus [\![\Lambda_0^{2,1}]\!] \oplus \Lambda^1$,

and so on. These are claimed to be irreducible $\mathrm{U}(n)$-decompositions, but I seem to find no explicit proof of this fact. A reference to a book of Weil ("Introduction à l'étude des variétés kähleriennes") is given, but I don't see an explicit argument in there - although the same claim appears. My knowledge of representation theory is limited, perhaps there are abstract ways to think of these decompositions.
What is a good way to see these decompositions? Is there any reference with explicit arguments?
